# Outputting ordinal numbers (1st, 2nd, 3rd)

Tags: code-golf, string, number

I would like to generate (as a return result of a function, or simply as the output of a program) the [ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_%28linguistics%29) suffix of a positive integer concatenated to the number.

Samples:

```
1st  
2nd  
3rd  
4th  
...  
11th  
12th  
13th  
...  
20th  
21st
22nd
23rd
24th
```

And so on, with the suffix repeating the initial 1-10 subpattern every 10 until 100, where the pattern ultimately starts over.

The input would be the number and the output the ordinal string as shown above.

What is the smallest algorithm for this?

Comment: Hi, NickC, and welcome to codegolf.SE!  Just to clarify, do you mean that we should read a number like `11` as input, and output e.g. `11th`?  Is each number in the input on a separate line, and should the output numbers be on separate lines too?  And do we need to handle more than one line of input?

Comment: Are you looking for smallest algorithm or smallest code?

Comment: @Ilmari I am looking for `11` as input and `11th` as output.  I don't mind if it processes multiple lines but what I had in mind was processing just a single number.

Comment: @M42 You know, I'm not really sure. I don't have a strict requirement - but I was probably thinking smallest algorithm.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Perl, 37 + 1 characters

```
s/1?\d\b/$&.((0,st,nd,rd)[$&]||th)/eg
```

This is a regexp substitution that appends the appropriate ordinal suffix to any numbers in `$_` that are not already followed by a letter.  To apply it to file input, use the `p` command line switch, like this:

```
perl -pe 's/1?\d\b/$&.((0,st,nd,rd)[$&]||th)/eg'
```

This is a complete Perl program that reads input from stdin and writes the processed output to stdout.  The actual code is 37 chars long, but the `p` switch [counts as one extra character](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions).

#### Sample input:

```
This is the 1 line of the sample input...
...and this is the 2.
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

#### Output:

```
This is the 1st line of the sample input...
...and this is the 2nd.
1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th 9th 10th
11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th 17th 18th 19th 20th
21st 22nd 23rd 24th 25th 26th 27th 28th 29th 30th
101st 102nd 103rd 104th 105th 106th 107th 108th 109th 110th
```

Numbers already followed by letters will be ignored, so feeding the output again through the filter won't change it.  Spaces, commas and periods between numbers are not treated specially, so they're assumed to separate numbers like any other punctuation.  Thus, e.g. `3.14159` becomes `3rd.14159th`.

#### How does it work?

- First, this is a global regexp replacement (`s///g`).  The regexp being matched is `1?\d\b`, where `\d` matches any digit and `\b` is a zero-width assertion matching the boundary between an alphanumeric and a non-alphanumeric character.  Thus, `1?\d\b` matches the last digit of any number, plus the previous digit if it happens to be `1`.
- In the substitution, which is evaluated as Perl code due to the `/e` switch, we take the matched string segment (`$&`) and append (`.`) to it the suffix obtained by using `$&` itself as an integer index to the list `(0,st,nd,rd)`; if this suffix is zero or undefined (i.e. when `$&` is zero or greater than three), the `||` operator replaces it with `th`.

---

**Edit:** If the input is restricted to a single integer, then this 35 character solution will suffice:

```
s/1?\d$/$&.((0,st,nd,rd)[$&]||th)/e
```

Comment: Should be able to drop the `g` off the substitution if you specify that each number must be on it's own line.  Also, that'd let you change the word boundary to be `$`.  But overall, +1, damn clever solution.

Comment: @GigaWatt: Indeed, I wrote the code before NickC answered my question about the input format, so I made it as generic as possible.

Comment: I know this is pretty old and rules were different, but using `$\ ` instead of `s///` shaves a few bytes off: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYlBCoQwEATv/Y4gK0ScmehJZB@y7i2CgmjQHPN2x6h96G6qwrgvrWrN38GbujND/yF7RLt6u/vyZ4p/SnFSZQgcGjCDBezADSRDgThI5pTFLYnoqfeSvEPutk9A5xbivK2HVmG5AA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: In fact, even shorter using `/.../g` syntax: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYnBDkAwEETv8x0OJBW7W47iQ9StgkRo6NG3W8UcZibvhfFYG9XMtTmZM5rNm8MXfcWd81k1DdcVZ1WGwKIGM1jAFlxDEhSIhSROSbySiL76L8k/ZF/7BXTvIS77dmoZ1gc "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 47):

## Python 2, 49 bytes

```python
lambda n:`n`+'tsnrhtdd'[n%5*(n%100^15>4>n%10)::4]
```

An anonymous function. A [full program](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?1st%202nd%203rd%204th/xsot_1456205408&py) would be counted at 55 bytes.

`'tsnrhtdd'[i::4]` encodes the suffixes `th st nd rd` for values of `i` from 0 to 3. Given this, all we need is a way to map the values of `n` to the index of the corresponding suffix, `i`. A straightforward expression that works is `(n%10)*(n%10<4 and not 10<n%100<14)`. We can easily shorten this by dropping the first set of parentheses and observing that `n%5` gives the same results as `n%10` for the values of `n` with the special suffixes. With a bit of trial and error, one may also shorten `not 10<n%100<14` to `n%100^15>4`, which can be chained with the other conditional to save even more bytes.

Comment: this is some black magic right here c:

Comment: http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/areyouawizard.png

Comment: the straightforward expression looks to have a mistake: the index should be non-zero if n%100 is _not_ between 10 and 14.

Comment: @jeje Good eye! I fixed up the explanation. Funny how this error has gone unnoticed for so many years.

Answer (score 13):

### Python, 68 characters

```
i=input()
k=i%10
print"%d%s"%(i,"tsnrhtdd"[(i/10%10!=1)*(k<4)*k::4])
```

Comment: This is really late, but you can take off 7 bytes by doing `\`i\`+"tsnrhtdd"`. Otherwise, this is the exact solution I just got.

Answer (score 13):

## Mathematica <s>39</s> 45 bytes

Note: In recent versions of Mathematica, asking for the `nth` part of `p`, where `p` is undefined, generates an error message,  but returns the correct answer anyway.  I've added `Quiet` to prevent the error message from printing.

```
Quiet@StringSplit[SpokenString[p[[#]]]][[2]]&
```

**Usage**

```
Quiet@StringSplit[SpokenString[p[[#]]]][[2]] &[31]
```

> 31st

```
Quiet@StringSplit[SpokenString[p[[#]]]][[2]] &/@Range[21]
```

> {"1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", 
>   "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "14th", "15th", "16th", "17th", 
>   "18th", "19th", "20th", "21st"}

---

**How it works**

`SpokenString` writes out an any valid Mathematica expression as it might be spoken. Below are two examples from the documentation for [SpokenString](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SpokenString.html),

```
SpokenString[Sqrt[x/(y + z)]]
```

> "square root of the quantity x over the quantity y plus z" *)

```
SpokenString[Graphics3D[Sphere[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]], "DetailedGraphics" -> True]
```

> "a three-dimensional graphic consisting of unit spheres centered at 0, 0, 0 and 1, 1, 1"

---

Now, for the example at hand,

```
Quiet@SpokenString[p[[#]]] &[31]
```

> "the 31st element of p"

Let's represent the above string as a list of words:

```
StringSplit[%]
```

> {"the", "31st", "element", "of", "p"}

and take the second element...

```
%[[2]]
```

> 31st

Comment: I'm confused; where is `p` defined?  EDIT: never mind, I see how you're using this; unfortunately it does not work on my system. :-/

Comment: It works on v.9.0.1. (I seem to recall that you are using 7.0.)  Yes, p does not need to be defined.

Comment: I understand that now.  However, in v7 I get from `SpokenString @ p[[117]]` the output `" part 117 of p"`.

Comment: So `SpokenString` gets revised from time to time. I wouldn't be surprised it this code (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8859/hello-world-in-1024-characters/8869#8869) also doesn't work on v. 7. BTW, it wasn't meant to be an enduring solution.

Comment: Hah, I hadn't seen that answer before.

Comment: Actually, I haven't seen a lot of your contributions to this site.  You're really going crazy here! (In a good way.)

Answer (score 12):

## Javascript (ES6) <s>50</s> 44 Bytes

```
a=>a+=[,"st","nd","rd"][a.match`1?.$`]||"th"
```

#### Notes

- takes imput as a string
- Removed 6 bytes, thanks @user81655

Comment: `a+` -> `a+=`, remove parentheses, `\d` -> `.`, remove `[0]`, and if you take the number as a string: `a.match\`1?.$\`` instead of `/1?.$/.exec(a)`.

Answer (score 9):

### Ruby, 60

It's not as good as the Perl entry, but I figured I'd work on my Ruby skills.

```
def o(n)n.to_s+%w{th st nd rd}[n/10%10==1||n%10>3?0:n%10]end
```

Function takes one integer argument, `n`, and returns a string as the ordinal form.

Works according to the following logic:
If the tens digit is a 1 or the ones digit is greater than 3 use the suffix 'th'; otherwise find the suffix from the array ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'] using the final digit as the index.

Comment: `o(113)` is `"113rd"`, should be `"113th"`. The tens digit check doesn't account for numbers with more than two digits.

Comment: Ok, pitched in another `%10` to compensate.  Added 3 characters.  (I feel like `%10` appears enough where it should be shortened somehow, but I can't think of a solution)

Comment: You can never beat Perl in writing horrible incomprehensible code that's as short as possible :)

Comment: Set a variable to `10`?

Comment: I think setting a variable to `n%10` is better.

Answer (score 6):

### Javascript, <del>68</del> 71

```
function o(n){return n+([,'st','nd','rd'][~~(n/10%10)-1?n%10:0]||'th')}
```

Joint effort with ItsCosmo.

EDIT: Wasn't working properly with numbers > 100

Comment: You could bring it down to 62 with: `function o(n)n+([,'st','nd','rd'][~~(n/10%10)-1?n%10:0]||'th')` and you can bring it down further to 54 if you are happy to use fat arrow notation: `o=n=>n+([,'st','nd','rd'][~~(n/10%10)-1?n%10:0]||'th')`

Comment: @WallyWest For some reason, I really like that my solution works in modern browsers. Feel free to post your own answer; I think its sufficiently different.

Comment: No, that's fine! Just providing a few alternatives!

Comment: I made it work with ARGV: ```for(n of arguments)print(n+([,'st','nd','rd'][~~(n/10%10)-1?n%10:0]||'th'))```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 64 characters (ES3) or 47 characters (ES6)

#### ES3 (64 characters):

`function(n){return n+=[,'st','nd','rd'][n%100>>3^1&&n%10]||'th'}`

#### ES6 (47 characters):

`n=>n+=[,'st','nd','rd'][n%100>>3^1&&n%10]||'th'`

#### Explanation

The expression `n % 100 >> 3 ^ 1` evaluates to 0 for any positive `n` ending with digits `08`–`15`. Thus, for any `n mod 100` ending in `11`, `12`, or `13`, the array lookup returns `undefined`, leading to a suffix of `th`.

For any positive `n` ending in other digits than `08`–`15`, the expression `n % 100 >> 3 ^ 1` evaluates to a positive integer, invoking the expression `n % 10` for array lookup, returning `st`,`nd`, or `rd` for `n` which ends with `1`, `2`, or `3`. Otherwise, `th`.

Comment: Save a bytes with `n+=[,'st','nd','rd'][n%100>>3^1&&n%10]||'th'`.

Comment: @Shaggy, thanks, updated as suggested.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/guest271314/SpeechSynthesisSSMLParser/blob/master/SpeechSynthesisSSMLParserTest.html#L64, https://github.com/guest271314/SpeechSynthesisSSMLParser/blob/master/SpeechSynthesisSSMLParserTest.html#L65

Comment: @guest271314, fun to see this code being used. Note that it only works for positive numbers, another alternative is `n+=[,"st","nd","rd"][(((n<0?-n:n)+90)%100-10)%10]||"th"`, adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39466341/6738706).

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>95</s> 100 chars

```
h=foldr g"th".show
g '1'"th"="1st"
g '2'"th"="2nd"
g '3'"th"="3rd"
g '1'[x,_,_]='1':x:"th"
g a s=a:s
```

Testing:

```
*Main> map h [1..40]
["1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th","7th","8th","9th","10th","11th","12th","13t
h","14th","15th","16th","17th","18th","19th","20th","21st","22nd","23rd","24th",
"25th","26th","27th","28th","29th","30th","31st","32nd","33rd","34th","35th","36
th","37th","38th","39th","40th"]
```

Must be loaded with -XNoMonomorphismRestriction.

Comment: I'm seeing 100 here, but [95 using an infix operator](https://tio.run/##NcqxCsMgFIXh3ae4uphAkBo3wTdIp44hiJCWW2pMUEvz9laHbOfj/OjS5@l9KWheu19jR3uWkYmE@49wyWmTYTJlRvh4cQxrpbqoYmON53Owg11M3frU7SSOJuN0Kpt7BzCwueNuoTu@@ZHjFEAA9jBLIdRtKX8).

Comment: thanks, fixed. probably didn't know we have to count the newlines as well, back then.

Answer (score 5):

## J -  <s>44</s>  41 char

Nothing in J? This is an outrage!

```
(":,th`st`nd`rd{::~4|4<.10(|*|~:-~)100&|)
```

Explained (note that `1` is boolean true in J and `0` is false):

- `100&|` - First, reduce the input modulo 100.
- `10(|*|~:-~)` - In this subexpression, `|` is the input mod 10 and `-~` is the input (mod 100) minus 10. You don't get many trains as clean as this one in J, so it's a treat to see here!

  - `~:` is not-equals, so `|~:-~` is false if the tens digit is 1 and true otherwise.
  - `*` is just multiplication, so we're taking the input mod 10 and multiplying by a boolean, which will zero it out if false. The result of this is "input mod 10, except 0 on the tens".
- `4|4<.` - Min (`<.`) the above with 4, to clamp down larger values, and then reduce modulo 4 so that they all go to zero.
- `` th`st`nd`rd{::~ `` - Use that as an index into the list of suiffixes. Numbers ending in X1 or X2 or X3, but not in 1X, will find their suffix, and everything else will take the 0th suffix `th`.
- `":,` - Finally, take the original input, convert it to a string (`":`), and append the suffix.

Usage is obvious, though as-is the verb can only take one ordinal, not a list.

```
   (":,th`st`nd`rd{::~4|4<.10(|*|~:-~)100&|) 112         NB. single use
112th
   (":,th`st`nd`rd{::~4|4<.10(|*|~:-~)100&|) 1 2 3 4 5   NB. doing it wrong
|length error
|       (":,th`st`nd`rd{::~4|4<.10(|*|~:-~)100&|)1 2 3 4 5
   NB. i.5 10   makes a 5x10 grid of increasing integers
   NB. &.>      to operate on each integer separately, and box the result after
   (":,th`st`nd`rd{::~4|4<.10(|*|~:-~)100&|)&.> i.5 10   NB. all better
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|0th |1st |2nd |3rd |4th |5th |6th |7th |8th |9th |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|10th|11th|12th|13th|14th|15th|16th|17th|18th|19th|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|20th|21st|22nd|23rd|24th|25th|26th|27th|28th|29th|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|30th|31st|32nd|33rd|34th|35th|36th|37th|38th|39th|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|40th|41st|42nd|43rd|44th|45th|46th|47th|48th|49th|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Alternative 41 char solution showing off a couple logical variants:

```
(":;@;st`nd`rd`th{~3<.10(|+3*|=-~)100|<:)
```

Previously I had an overlong explanation of this 44 char hunk of junk. `10 10#:` takes the last two decimal digits and `/@` puts logic between them.

```
(":,th`st`nd`rd{::~10 10(]*[(~:*])4>])/@#:])
```

Answer (score 4):

### Golfscript, 34 characters

```
~.10/10%1=!1$10%*.4<*'thstndrd'2/=
```

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, <s>75</s> 60

With the new arrow notation:

```
o=(s)=>s+((0|s/10%10)==1?"th":[,"st","nd","rd"][s%10]||"th")
```

*Old version, without arrow notation (75 chars):*

```
function o(s){return s+((0|s/10%10)==1?"th":[,"st","nd","rd"][s%10]||"th")}
```

Comment: [52 bytes (V8)](https://tio.run/##FclLCoMwEADQq5SBQkL8JNCF1I4eRFyInzolOCUTXHn3qJu3eb9hH2QM9I/5XiXGJNiIUVI6@3QW0bUQV3h3GUiEDLbpIkzQd3J1fxz36rRwUH6OD0Jb0@flajJGj7wJ@7nw/FWsSOt0Ag "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>38</s> 36 bytes

Thanks to ngn for fixing a bug while maintaining byte count.

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Requires `⎕IO` (**I**ndex **O**rigin) set to `0`, which is default on many systems. Even works for 0!

```apl
⍕,{2↑'thstndrd'↓⍨2×⊃⍵⌽∊1 0 8\⊂10↑⍳4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qZv6jtgkG/9OA5KPeqTrVRo/aJqqXZBSX5KUUpag/apv8qHeF0eHpj7qaH/VufdSz91FHl6GCgYJFzKOuJkMDoOJHvZtNav//T1Mw4EpTMARiIwUFIGkMJk2ApLqenp46SM4QLGQIkTc0RpIyMgCLGYG1G4EIYxBhAgA)

`{`…`}` anonymous lambda; `⍵` is argument:

`⍳4` first four **ɩ**ndices; `[0,1,2,3]`

`10↑` take first ten elements from that, padding with zeros: `[0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

`⊂` enclose to treat as single element; `[[0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0]]`

`1 0 8\` expand to one copy, a prototypical copy (all-zero), eight copies;
  `[[0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0],`
   `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],`
   `[0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0],`
   `[0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0],`
   ⋮ (5 more)
   `[0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0]]`

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten);
  `[0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,`
   `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,`
   `0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,`
   `0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,`
   ⋮ (50 more)
   `0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

`⍵⌽` cyclically rotate left as many steps as indicated by the argument

`⊃` pick the first number (i.e. the argument-mod-100'th number)

`2×` multiply two by that (gives `0`, `2`, `4`, or `6`)

`'thstndrd'↓⍨`drop that many characters from this string

`2↑` take the first two of the remaining characters

`⍕,` concatenate the stringified argument to that

Comment: "31th"?­­­­­­­­

Comment: `⍕,{2↑'thstndrd'↓⍨2×⊃⍵⌽∊1 0 8\⊂10↑⍳4}`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention `⎕io←0`. I can see you guessed that, but there are a few 1,2,3,4,0,0... that should be 0,1,2,3,0,0...

Comment: @ngn Fixed. And happens to work for 0 too!

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>79</s> 76 bytes

Since there is no R solution yet... no tricks here, basic vector indexing, golfed down 3 chars thanks to Giuseppe. Previously tried index: `[1+(x%%10)-(x%%100==11)]` and `[1+(x%%10)*(x%%100!=11)]`.

```r
function(x)paste0(x,c("th","st","nd","rd",rep("th",6))[1+x%%10*!x%%100==11])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfbqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0KzILG4JNVAo0InWUOpJENJR6m4BEjkpQCJIiBRlFoAETfT1Iw21K5QVTU00FIEUwa2toaGsZr/ixMLCnIqNQytDA0NddI1uf4DAA)

With `substr`, 79 bytes:

```r
function(x,y=1+2*min(x%%10-(x%%100==11),4))paste0(x,substr("thstndrdth",y,y+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrLCoMwEEbhvY8hCJk6Qn7pqpiHSb1Dm4bMCM3TR8HV@RYnlXXoynKEUfdfMH/ODm3/@O6Xmwa2u2OdA4ifRNGLzvYa5XiLJlPrJhqmNOlWc@bcgqiIj/GTDV4AeKWqnA)

Comment: `1+x%%10*!x%%100==11` for the index?

Comment: @Giuseppe I need to calm down on the parenthesis :). Clever use of `!` in front of expression instead of `!=`.

Comment: Yeah, the operators have weird precedence; `^` is really high, then `%%`-type operators, then `*/` and `+-` and I think `==` and `&|` comes next. `!` has quite low precedence so you can use it as a separator between operations.

Answer (score 4):

Bash (Cardinal to ordinal) **91** Bytes:

```
function c(){ case "$1" in *1[0-9]|*[04-9])"$1"th;;*1)"$1"st;;*2)"$1"nd;;*3)"$1"rd;;esac }
```

Comment: You can save _at least_ 2 bytes in your solution, just rename your `c2o` function something with a 1-byte name.

Comment: [58 bytes.](https://tio.run/##DcvBCsMgEATQe75iD0uJQsEtXoqUfkgtxKolpWCIKzQH/93uYZgHw7wCryPOah4xcAYk@JRJ073rh7Hn61MhtdU5TQJugougJIF0TVPmEIdy763CIVdYOO9AYM3i0gYR8Oin8PuCR3PzaHur4H2RNNlLHn8 "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: Wow @tailsparkrabbitear I think you should write an answer. Or do you want me to edit my answer?

Comment: If you say so; posted mine.

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, 92

```
process{"$_$(switch -r($_){"(?<!1)1$"{'st'}"(?<!1)2$"{'nd'}"(?<!1)3$"{'rd'}default{'th'}})"}
```

Works with one number per line of input. Input is given through the pipeline. Making it work for only a single number doesn't reduce the size.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, 151

I know that this program is not comparable to the others. Just felt like giving a solution.

```
<?$s=explode(' ',trim(fgets(STDIN)));foreach($s as$n){echo$n;echo(int)(($n%100)/10)==1?'th':($n%10==1?'st':($n%10==2?'nd':($n%10==3?'rd':'th')))."\n";}
```

Comment: you can save a few characters by using ```foreach($s as $n){echo$n;```

Answer (score 3):

## K - 44 char

It so happens that this is exactly as long as the J, and works in almost the same way.

```
{x,$`th`st`nd`rd@{y*(y<4)*~1=x}.-2#0,.:'x$:}
```

Explained:

- `x$:` - First, we convert the operand `x` into a string, and then assign that back to `x`. We will need its string rep again later, so doing it now saves characters.
- `.:'` - Convert (`.:`) each (`'`) digit back into a number.
- `-2#0,` - Append a 0 to the front of the list of digits (in case of single-digit numbers), and then take the last two.
- `{y*(y<4)*~1=x}.` - Use the two digits as arguments `x` and `y` to this inner function, which returns `y` if `y` is less than 4 and `x` is not equal to 1, otherwise 0.
- `` `th`st`nd`rd@ `` - Index the list of suffixes by this result.
- `x,$` - Convert the suffix from symbol to string, and append it to the original number.

Usage:

```
  {x,$`th`st`nd`rd@{y*(y<4)*~1=x}.-2#0,.:'x$:} 3021
"3021st"
  {x,$`th`st`nd`rd@{y*(y<4)*~1=x}.-2#0,.:'x$:}' 1 2 3 4 11 12 13 14  /for each in list
("1st"
 "2nd"
 "3rd"
 "4th"
 "11th"
 "12th"
 "13th"
 "14th")
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 98 bytes

```
function c($n){$c=$n%100;$s=['','st','nd','rd'];echo$c>9&&$c<14||!$s[$c%10]?$n.'th':$n.$s[$c%10];}
```

The 11-13 bit is killing me here.  Works for any integer `$n >= 0`.

For any integer `$n`:

## PHP, 103 bytes

```
function c($n){$c=abs($n%100);$s=['','st','nd','rd'];echo$c>9&&$c<14||!$s[$c%10]?$n.'th':$n.$s[$c%10];}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, 52 chars

```
n=>n+(!/1.$/.test(--n)&&'snr'[n%=10]+'tdd'[n]||'th')
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 62 bytes

```
n=>n+(n/10%10==1||(n%=10)<1||n>3?"th":n<2?"st":n<3?"nd":"rd");
```

Full program and verification:

```
using System;

namespace OutputOrdinalNumbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<int,string>f= n=>n+(n/10%10==1||(n%=10)<1||n>3?"th":n<2?"st":n<3?"nd":"rd");
    
            for (int i=1; i<=124; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(f(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can golf it by two bytes by changing the `||` to `|`.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 29 + 5 = 34 bytes

```
SpokenStringDump`SpeakOrdinal
```

+5 bytes because `Speak` function must be called before using this built-in.

**Usage**

```
SpokenStringDump`SpeakOrdinal[1]
```

> `"1st "`

```
SpokenStringDump`SpeakOrdinal[4707]
```

> `"4,707th "`

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>91</s> 81 bytes

```
String d(int n){return n+(n/10%10==1|(n%=10)<1|n>3?"th":n<2?"st":n<3?"nd":"rd");}
```

Port from [*@adrianmp*'s C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94774/52210).

Old answer (**91 bytes**):

```
String c(int n){return n+((n%=100)>10&n<14?"th":(n%=10)==1?"st":n==2?"nd":n==3?"rd":"th");}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/pA66N2)

```
class M{
  static String c(int n){
    return n + ((n%=100) > 10 & n < 14
                ?"th"
                : (n%=10) == 1
                   ? "st"
                   : n == 2
                      ? "nd"
                      : n == 3
                         ? "rd"
                         :"th");
  }

  static String d(int n){
    return n + (n/10%10 == 1 | (n%=10) < 1 | n > 3
                 ? "th"
                 : n < 2
                    ? "st"
                    : n < 3
                       ? "nd"
                       :"rd");
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    for(int i = 1; i < 201; i++){
      System.out.print(c(i) + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 1; i < 201; i++){
      System.out.print(d(i) + ", ");
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th, 15th, 16th, 17th, 18th, 19th, 20th, 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 24th, 25th, 26th, 27th, 28th, 29th, 30th, 31st, 32nd, 33rd, 34th, 35th, 36th, 37th, 38th, 39th, 40th, 41st, 42nd, 43rd, 44th, 45th, 46th, 47th, 48th, 49th, 50th, 51st, 52nd, 53rd, 54th, 55th, 56th, 57th, 58th, 59th, 60th, 61st, 62nd, 63rd, 64th, 65th, 66th, 67th, 68th, 69th, 70th, 71st, 72nd, 73rd, 74th, 75th, 76th, 77th, 78th, 79th, 80th, 81st, 82nd, 83rd, 84th, 85th, 86th, 87th, 88th, 89th, 90th, 91st, 92nd, 93rd, 94th, 95th, 96th, 97th, 98th, 99th, 100th, 101st, 102nd, 103rd, 104th, 105th, 106th, 107th, 108th, 109th, 110th, 111th, 112th, 113th, 114th, 115th, 116th, 117th, 118th, 119th, 120th, 121st, 122nd, 123rd, 124th, 125th, 126th, 127th, 128th, 129th, 130th, 131st, 132nd, 133rd, 134th, 135th, 136th, 137th, 138th, 139th, 140th, 141st, 142nd, 143rd, 144th, 145th, 146th, 147th, 148th, 149th, 150th, 151st, 152nd, 153rd, 154th, 155th, 156th, 157th, 158th, 159th, 160th, 161st, 162nd, 163rd, 164th, 165th, 166th, 167th, 168th, 169th, 170th, 171st, 172nd, 173rd, 174th, 175th, 176th, 177th, 178th, 179th, 180th, 181st, 182nd, 183rd, 184th, 185th, 186th, 187th, 188th, 189th, 190th, 191st, 192nd, 193rd, 194th, 195th, 196th, 197th, 198th, 199th, 200th, 
1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th, 15th, 16th, 17th, 18th, 19th, 20th, 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 24th, 25th, 26th, 27th, 28th, 29th, 30th, 31st, 32nd, 33rd, 34th, 35th, 36th, 37th, 38th, 39th, 40th, 41st, 42nd, 43rd, 44th, 45th, 46th, 47th, 48th, 49th, 50th, 51st, 52nd, 53rd, 54th, 55th, 56th, 57th, 58th, 59th, 60th, 61st, 62nd, 63rd, 64th, 65th, 66th, 67th, 68th, 69th, 70th, 71st, 72nd, 73rd, 74th, 75th, 76th, 77th, 78th, 79th, 80th, 81st, 82nd, 83rd, 84th, 85th, 86th, 87th, 88th, 89th, 90th, 91st, 92nd, 93rd, 94th, 95th, 96th, 97th, 98th, 99th, 100th, 101st, 102nd, 103rd, 104th, 105th, 106th, 107th, 108th, 109th, 110th, 111th, 112th, 113th, 114th, 115th, 116th, 117th, 118th, 119th, 120th, 121st, 122nd, 123rd, 124th, 125th, 126th, 127th, 128th, 129th, 130th, 131st, 132nd, 133rd, 134th, 135th, 136th, 137th, 138th, 139th, 140th, 141st, 142nd, 143rd, 144th, 145th, 146th, 147th, 148th, 149th, 150th, 151st, 152nd, 153rd, 154th, 155th, 156th, 157th, 158th, 159th, 160th, 161st, 162nd, 163rd, 164th, 165th, 166th, 167th, 168th, 169th, 170th, 171st, 172nd, 173rd, 174th, 175th, 176th, 177th, 178th, 179th, 180th, 181st, 182nd, 183rd, 184th, 185th, 186th, 187th, 188th, 189th, 190th, 191st, 192nd, 193rd, 194th, 195th, 196th, 197th, 198th, 199th, 200th,
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
∆o2NȯJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiIZvMk7Ir0oiLCIiLCIyMyJd)

Answer (score 1):

## OCaml

I'm pretty new to OCaml, but this is the shortest i could get.

```
let n x =
   let v = x mod 100 and string_v = string_of_int x in
   let z = v mod 10 in
   if v=11 || v=12 || v=13 then string_v^"th" 
   else if v = 1 || z = 1 then string_v^"st" else if v = 2 || z = 2 then string_v^"nd" else if v = 3 || z = 3 then string_v^"rd" else string_v^"th";;
```

I created a function n that takes a number as a parameter and does the work. Its long but thought it'd be great to have a functional example.

Comment: input: 11 would yield output: 11st

Comment: yeah, you're right.. I've made the correction. Thanks

Comment: I've just tidied up the formatting on your code. Each line needs to be preceded by four spaces in order to be recognized as a code block.

Comment: Wouldn't your first if check be shorter as `if v>10 && v<14`? I'm not familiar with ocaml, but is it necessary to have the `string_v` variable be so long?

Comment: No its not necessary, I could have chosen w or x. Just wanted something meaningful.  
But you're right, it would have made the code a little shorter.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Please include your byte count on the header. (too late?)

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7, 137 chars

```
def b(n):
 for e,o in[[i,'th']for i in['11','12','13']+list('4567890')]+[['2','nd'],['1','st'],['3','rd']]:
  if n.endswith(e):return n+o
```

`n` should be a string

I know I'm beaten by the competition here already, but I thought I'd provide my idea anyways

this just basically generates a list of key, value pairs with number (as a string) ending `e` and the ordinal `o`. It attempts to match 'th' first (hence why I didn't use a dictionary), so that it won't accidentally return 'st', for example, when it should be 'th'. This will work for any positive integer

Comment: `n[-1]==e` is 5 chars shorter than `n.endswith(e)`

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala 86

```
def x(n:Int)=n+{if(n%100/10==1)"th"else(("thstndrd"+"th"*6).sliding(2,2).toSeq(n%10))}
```

Scala 102:

```
def x(n:Int)=if((n%100)/10==1)n+"th"else if(n%10<4)n+("thstndrd".take(n+1)%5*2.drop(n%5*2))else n+"th"
```

102 as well:

```
def x(n:Int)=if((n%100)/10==1)n+"th"else if(n%10<4)n+("thstndrd".sliding(2,2).toSeq(n%10))else n+"th"
```

ungolfed:

```
def x (n: Int) =
  n + { if (((n % 100) / 10) == 1) "th" 
        else (("thstndrd"  + ("th"  * 6)).sliding (2, 2).toSeq (n % 10))
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

## C: 95 characters

A ridiculously long solution:

```
n;main(){scanf("%d",&n);printf("%d%s",n,n/10%10-1&&(n=n%10)<4&&n?n>2?"rd":n<2?"st":"nd":"th");}
```

It needs to be mangled more.

Comment: A user flagged this saying *"is incorrect: doesn't loop at all, i.e. it works just for a given number, not _all_ numbers below it. see ideone.com/pO6UwV ."* That's not a reason to flag as moderators do not judge correctness, but it may be an issue.

Comment: Based upon this comment from the question creator: "@Ilmari I am looking for 11 as input and 11th as output. I don't mind if it processes multiple lines but what I had in mind was processing just a single number. – NickC Jan 20 '12 at 21:00" it is doing what it should.

I.e. it only should process a single number.

Comment: sorry for that flag; I misread the requirement, and didn't have enough rep at the time, to comment directly. Sorry again. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Haxe, 83 chars

```
function o(n:Int){return ['th','st','nd','rd'][n%100>20||n%100<4?n%10>3?0:n%10:0];}
```

Based on the javascript version, fixed for n > 100 as well.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Remove all whitespace to save some bytes. Right now, I count 91 total. 2) This doesn't seem to be a full program or a function. Perhaps you should consider turning it into one of those.

Comment: 1) yeah, but thats quite straightforward, so I tried to stay readable.

Comment: 2) yeah, you're right, I just pasted it here so anyone can use it without reconverting from another lang. :)

Answer (score 1):

## C - <strike>95</strike> 83 characters

```
main(n,k){scanf("%d",&n);k=(n+9)%10;printf("%d%s\n",n,k<3?"st\0nd\0rd"+3*k:"th");}
```

Degolfed:

```
main(n,k)
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    k=(n+9)%10; // xx1->0, xx2->1, xx3->2
    printf("%d%s\n",n,k<3?"st\0nd\0rd"+3*k:"th");
}
```

We could do `k=(n-1)%10` instead of adding 9, but for n=0 we would get an incorrect behaviour,
because in C `(-1)%10` evaluates to -1, not 9.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 75

```
function s(i){return i+'thstndrd'.substr(~~(i/10%10)-1&&i%10<4?i%10*2:0,2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 101 bytes

```
SELECT:1||DECODE(ROUND(MOD(:1,100),-1),10,'th',DECODE(MOD(:1,10),1,'st',2,'nd',3,'rd','th'))FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>88</s> 84 bytes

```
lambda x:x+((('th','st','nd','rd')+('th',)*6)[int(x[-1])]if('0'+x)[-2]!='1'else'th')
```

Ungolfed:

```
def y(x):
    return x + (('th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd') + ('th', ) * 6)[int(x[-1])] if ('0' + x)[-2] != '1' else 'th')
```

`lambda x` defines an anonymous function with parameter `x`. `((('th','st','nd','rd')+('th',)*6)[int(x[-1])]` defines a tuple of the endings for numbers less than 10, the `0-th` element is for `0`, and so forth. the `if ('0'+x)[-2] != '1'` checks if there is `11`, `12`, or a `13` to fix, and adds then `else 'th'` adds `th` instead of `st`, `rd`, or `nd`.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it took me a while to go through and understand it. If you could add a code explanation and breakdown below the golfed version of your code, it would help people learn from your code and improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: Ok, I will. Should I also add an un-golfed answer?

Comment: It shouldn't be a different answer... What you've done is fine, well done. If you want any more challenges to do, I could give some recommendations.

Comment: Ok. You could try... [Adjust your chair](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66994/adjust-your-chair), or [Where will your buddies sit](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49589/where-will-your-buddies-sit). Or you could try some of [my challenges](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A43394+is%3Aquestion+duplicate%3Ano), such as [The Knight's Next Tour](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73759/the-knights-next-tour). If these aren't the sort of challenges you like, just say.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala 2.11.7, 151 Chars

```scala
def o(x:Int*)=x map{
case a if(a%10)==1&&a%100!=11=>a+"st"
case b if(b%10)==2&&b%100!=12=>b+"nd"
case c if(c%10)==3&&c%100!=13=>c+"rd"
case e=>e+"th"
}
```

Usage

```
   o(1,2,3,4) -> ArrayBuffer("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th")
```

Comment: Sorry, but all answers need to be golfed. Please golf this, if not than it's invalid and must be deleted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can remove the space between `map` and `{`, `:` and `Int*`, and remove the newline between `"th"` and `}` (I don't know Scala, so I might be completely wrong). Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 63

```
(format t"~a~a"i(let((x(format()"~:r"i)))(subseq x(-(length x)2))))
```

Input is `i`. There's probably a more clever way to golf this.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 33 bytes

```
+Q@.>+c"stndrd"2*]"th"7 1?qh`Q\1Z
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BQ%40.%3E%2Bc%22stndrd%222%2a%5D%22th%227+1%3Fqh%60Q%5C1Z&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A19%0A20%0A21%0A22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Procedural Footnote Language](https://github.com/vasilescur/pfl), 39 bytes

```
[1]
[PFL1.0]
[1] [ORD:[INPUT]]
[PFLEND]
```

The `BODY` section of the document contains a reference to footnote `[1]`; footnote `[1]` contains the `[ORD]`inal representation of the `[INPUT]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes

credit to @KevinCruijssen for improving the answer

```javascript
n=>n+=[,'st','nd','rd'][~~(n/10%10)-1?n%10:0]||'th'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9v@z/P1i5P2zZaR724RF1HPS8FSBSlqMdG19Vp5OkbGqgaGmjqGtrnAWkrg9iaGvWSDPX/yfl5xfk5qXo5@eka@RqGmppcqCJGGCLGGCImGCKGmAYZYppkiGmUERYXYGo0MsZiI1DnfwA)

---

## Explanation :

```javascript
n =>                      // input
    n+=[,'st','nd','rd']     // the array of suffices add everything to n
        [~~(n/10%10)-1?n%10:0] // the full magic 
    || 'th'               // works for everything except 1 , 2 , 3 just like what you want
```

---

Comment: "The full magic". The one bit I actually wanted to read the comments on :)

Comment: @SteveBennett The general logic that if the tens digit (`(n/10%10)`, rounded by the `~~`) is a one (`-1`)  then just get the index `0`, which maps to `th`, otherwise get the index of the ones digit, which will be the appropriate suffix for `1`,`2` and `3`, and `th` otherwise

Comment: [47](https://tio.run/##DcTLCoUgEADQX4mBQrGHQougaz8SBdFzQpqLI636d@sszjndE88e/6G4m0g2su1YiT4HDpDDtXz5BYbejFwZnRqdZfw9PA@EA2TcyAu3hgStbvFXmxaVkjNdTG4tHe2CBEoZXw)

Comment: Combining with [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119563/) is 46 but not not sure which to collect

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 68 bytes

```julia
f(x,m=x%10,p=x%100-m)="$x$(["th","st","nd","rd"][m>3||p==10?1:m+1])"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/TaNCJ9e2QtXQQKcATBno5mraKqlUqGhEK5VkKOkoFZcAibwUIFGUohQbnWtnXFNTYGtraGBvaJWrbRirqfQ/Lb9IIVMhM0/B0MrYgIuzoCgzryQnTyNNI1NTkys1L@U/AA)

Straightforward remainder rules in Julia.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
т%T‰ć≠*4ªß…thŠØ3ôsè¨«
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9vc2FiaWX//9GCJVTigLDEh@KJoCo0xaHDn@KApnRoxaDDmDPDtHPDqMKowqv//zEy) or [verify a few more test cases at once](https://tio.run/##LYw9CsJAFISvEgI2MsW@9zZ/VS5hJxYKglYWESFdsFDsxMrO2EjAxsITZM0BvMJeZN0Ei4GZge/bFPPFeul2ZR4G9nAJwrw0Z/fdjya2en2O9lSPdXc3N1s9tquuNlcx78I0bdM@HdyUwBBoRIiRIEUGUiACMUhAGhSBYlACSkEZWIE9w2ABa3AEIYh3CMRbPKv6eEEvUcMYVt/@P81@).

**Explanation:**

Mostly ported from a sub-section of [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181508/52210), except with additional leading `т%`.

```python
т%                     # Take modulo-100 on the (implicit) input-integer
  T‰                   # Take the divmod-10 ([n//10,n%10]) on that
    ć                  # Extract the head: n//10
     ≠                 # Check that it's NOT equal to 1 (0 if 1; 1 otherwise)
      *                # Multiply the [n%10] by this
       4ª              # Append a 4 to this list: [n%10*(n//10!=1),4]
         ß             # Pop and push the smallest number in this list
          …thŠØ        # Push dictionary string "th standards"
               3ô      # Split it into parts of size 3: ["th ","sta","nda","rds"]
                 sè    # Index the calculated minimum into this list
                       # (modular 0-based, so both 0 and 4 will index into "th ")
                   ¨   # Remove the last character
                    «  # And append it to the (implicit) input-integer
                       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `…thŠØ` is `"th standards"`.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 38 chars, 76 bytes

```
(⍕,{((⍳3)⍳10∣⍵×3≠⌊√⍵)⊃'snrt',¨'tddh'})
```

test:

```
  h←(⍕,{((⍳3)⍳10∣⍵×3≠⌊√⍵)⊃'snrt',¨'tddh'})
  h¨0..19
 0th 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th 9th 10th 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th 17th 18th 19th 
  h¨20..31
 20th 21st 22nd 23rd 24th 25th 26th 27th 28th 29th 30th 31st 
  ⎕fmt h¨100..104
┌5───────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌5─────┐ ┌5─────┐ ┌5─────┐ ┌5─────┐ ┌5─────┐│
││ 100th│ │ 101st│ │ 102nd│ │ 103rd│ │ 104th││
│└──────┘ └──────┘ └──────┘ └──────┘ └──────┘2
└∊───────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I don't think you need the outermost parens (or is it a weak point of NARS?)

Comment: @Bubbler I remember without parentesis () does not assign to "h"  name

Comment: for me is ok in that way

Answer (score 1):

## [FEU](https://github.com/TryItOnline/feu), 41 bytes

```
m/1.$/\0th/1$/1st/2$/2nd/3$/3rd/\d$/\0th/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0st/f8/V99QT0U/xqAkQ99QRd@wuETfSEXfKC9F31hF37goRT8mBSr7/7@hkTEA)

Comment: This doesn't work for numbers that end in `th` unless they have a one as the second last digit. I think you can solve this by adding `/\d$/\0th/` to the end. You can also golf the first part to be `/1.$/\0th/`

Comment: @JoKing Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 87 bytes (correct teen handling)

This C solution is longer than the current shortest 83 byte C solution posted, but as of writing, that 83 byte solution is incorrect and prints numbers like 11st, 12nd, and 13rd.

Here is my solution, which correctly handles teen numbers:

```
main(n){scanf("%d",&n);printf("%d%s",n,"th\0st\0nd\0rd"+(n%10<4&&n/10%10-1?n%10*3:0));}
```

Degolfed:

```
main(n) {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d%s", n, "th\0st\0nd\0rd" + (n%10 < 4 && n/10%10 - 1 ? n%10*3 : 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 58 bytes

Just a modification of @stephanmg's post in Bash.
Output is on STDERR as in "command not found".

```bash
case $1 in
*1?|*[04-9])$1th;;*1)$1st;;*2)$1nd;;*)$1rd
esac
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvBCsMgEATQe75iD0uJQsEtXoqUfkgtxKolpWCIKzQH/93uYZgHw7wCryPOah4xcAYk@JRJ073rh7Hn61MhtdU5TQJugougJIF0TVPmEIdy763CIVdYOO9AYM3i0gYR8Oin8PuCR3PzaHur4H2RNNlLHn8)

This program completely relies on the limitation that the input is a non-negative decimal integer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 23 bytes

```
₀%:4<?₀ḭċ∧*4«∨¦İk√«/$i+
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%80%25%3A4%3C%3F%E2%82%80%E1%B8%AD%C4%8B%E2%88%A7*4%C2%AB%E2%88%A8%C2%A6%C4%B0k%E2%88%9A%C2%AB%2F%24i%2B&inputs=1&header=&footer=)

###### Explanation:

```
₀%:4<?₀ḭċ∧*4«∨¦İk√«/$i+    # full program

₀%:                         # push input mod 10 twice
   4<                       # less than 4
     ?₀ḭ                    # input floor div 10
        ċ                   # != 1
         ∧*                 # and both bools, then multiply by initial mod 10
            4«∨¦İk√«/       # "thstndrd" split into 4 parts
                      $i    # indexed by input mod 10
                        +   # concat
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
ÞoÞ∞ZƛhṘ2ẎṘntp
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnm/DnuKInlrGm2jhuZgy4bqO4bmYbnRwIiwiIiwiIl0=)

```
ÞoÞ∞Z          # Zip ordinals with positive integers
     ƛ         # Over each
      hṘ2ẎṘ    # Get the last two characters of the ordinal
           ntp # Append the number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 313 bytes

This was painful. Setup could probably be golfed better. May write a half-decent explanation later.

```
++++[>++++++<-]>-[<+++++>-]<[->+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+<<<<<<<<]>->--------------->----->--------------->>+>+>----------->>>>+>+>+>,[.>,]<<<[-]>>>-[>+<-----]>---[-<<-<->>>]<<<-[[-]>[->+>++<<]>+<+++++[->-[>]<<<]>[<<<]>[>>[-<<<<<[<]<<<<<[>]<[[->+<]<]>>>>>>>>>[-<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>]>>>>>[>]>>>>]<<<]]<<<[<]<<[<]<<<[<]>>>>>>>.>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LCgIxDPygbArew/zIkIMKgggeBL@/5tGV3Sk0bTKP3D7X5/vxvb/mlAAhBVOH0uoNdaNCzscWggc9A4f70C3dqYFltnFg8zBjxCKCw74onnyqmVrSk6JMUu8jGS@9ZXRC57UR@wZSmrbmXWPOlMY/gxqLFJC91UN2LU/fbdqLf/3AmPPyAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>173</s> 110 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func o(n int){s,k:="th",n%10
if k>0&&k<4&&n/10%10!=1{s=[]string{"st","nd","rd"}[k-1]}
Print(n,s)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU5BDoIwEDzTV6xNJBBAW-PBCDU-wbvxQNRiU9kaWk6El3ghJt78kL-xqJedzcxkZu6PygyvW3nUZXWGulT4bJ3MVm9U9c00bkZl7SiRLR7BRAgKXdzZVK8FdRea4pQzoiToDQtDXSzDEOeceXIieGfF_mBdo7DqqHU0pXjypznRfq8zfujJzmsuwtTG_b91-y0aZ0QxdCSQpgEFawE891gIWDDmvyQZxcBEKs6_IVfvJ0FP_jnD8MMP)

- -47 bytes from using slice indexing (by @Steffan)
- -14 bytes from outputting to STDOUT (by @Steffan)
- -2 bytes from removing duplicate `n%10`.

#### Old answer, 173 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func o(n int)string{s:=Sprint(n)
switch n%100{case 11,12,13:s+="th"
default:switch n%10{case 1:s+="st"
case 2:s+="nd"
case 3:s+="rd"
default:s+="th"}}
return s}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY9NioNAEIXX9ikKIdCNmWA7m2Aic4XAnKBR2zTRaukuyUI8STYyMLvJgXKb8W-RVb1HPb569fip7PjXqvymqhIaZfC3I_1xfD1N01pHh1A3FDLdYQ6WIxgk4ckZrHqfZt_tpIijYP5uKL8C7mQc97nyJUi5l8lefqY-ykK6hqwotepqSt-iW3KJ-OnMYpPFYrHZFeCKN8AKHAbmSuocgh-20l9Lz_kLLqBngbYODKQZyNM0zxkkcTypKJqXwWUuXyO33AjBgoFtmHFc5z8)

Comment: [126 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BasMwEEXX1immggQJN4kUuihp1F6hkGXIwiSRK1qPjDReGfci3ZhCd71QbhMp8Wbeh_l_5v_81n78b6vjZ1Wfoakc_nVkF8-Xb9e0PtCS24Y4sx0ewQsEhyQjBYd1HzeG0wdnzgLOtHpV83nm9ilxpVWSD0b30ewPU4BH4o8cT2mEEx_22b3Qh4GFM3UBYdcmGwmUZRymFm-3x7mWkNCzwvoADjYG9Evi1sBaqaTKMi-L95z_QuGFk5IVA5vOjOOdVw)

Comment: Or [112 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BDoIwFETX9BTfJhIIoK1xYYAaj-CesCBosVFaQsuKcBI3xMSdF_I2FmTz3yQzmfnPV6XGT1OU96K6Ql0I-e4Mjw7fRtSNas0G89pgxDtZgvIkCGn8XscMmxtGgoNcU3Ikrjsx3VtuKbFyxWivWZZr0wpZ9VgbHGJ5sae94CGb0hHNB3S2tvFkqP1h2T3NU9Mjng89crhqQUDMgCaWKYMdIVYFwWQ6yhN-Mpc8bB45A1p6xvHPHw) by outputting to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), idk bytes

[image: Scratch!]

I tried to convert it to sb syntax, but it did not work

[Try it!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/546066231/fullscreen/)

Please comment if you know a way to golf, or byte-count this

Comment: It's 295 bytes.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/673/34718