# Swap the Alphabet

Tags: code-golf, string, substitution

In this challenge, you will be "reversing" the alphabet or swapping `a-z` with `z-a`. This is commonly known as the [Atbash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash) cypher.

Because this transformation makes the output look like some foreign language, your code will need to be as short as possible.

---

### Examples

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba

Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou

Hello, World!
Svool, Dliow!
```

### Specification

- The input may contain multiple lines, and will be ASCII-only
- **No** *additional* whitespace should be added to the output
- Case *must* be preserved

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=68504,OVERRIDE_USER=40695;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: +1 for the justification *"Because this transformation makes the output look like some foreign language, your code will need to be as short as possible."*

Comment: Some Trivia: this is [Atbash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash), a known cipher as old as the bible.

Comment: "Because this transformation makes the output look like some foreign language, your code will need to be as short as possible."

What kind of logic is that??

Because your description raises about as much question marks as if it was written in some foreign language your answer to this question should be in intelligible natural language and some verbosity is appreciated.

Comment: Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou should be the new site for "Programming Trivials & Code Bowling"...

Comment: Why don't you allow additional whitespace? That makes it impossible in some languages that always have a trailing newline. I can't see it adding anything to the challenge.

Comment: The specifications do not say whether we keep the capitalisation or not

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Pyth, 8 bytes

```
XXzG)rG1
```

@xnor suggested this simpler approach on @FryAmTheEggman's Pyth answer, then I translated it to Pyth.

This uses the handy behavior of `X` (translate) when given only two arguments: it translates from the second argument to the reversed second argument. We do this first with the lowercase alphabet (`G`), and then with uppercased `G`.

Answer (score 17):

## C, 59 bytes

Sorry for bringing up C again, but I was a bit disappointed to see only C *functions* here. I was under the impression OP was looking for a usable product.

```
main(c){while(~(c=getchar()))putchar(isalpha(c)?c+4^31:c);}
```

Compiled on Ubuntu 14.04 with a simple:

```
cc swalpha.c
```

The resulting executable reads any number of lines from stdin, and writes the result to stdout.

Thanks to so many of the other posters for the XOR trick.

Comment: This was the most extreme compact program that does something remarkably amazing like this!  @Ruud Helderman  this was extremely well done!

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>69</s> 67 bytes

```js
x=>x.replace(/[A-Z]/gi,c=>String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt()+4^31))
```

Uses the same strategy as my [Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68509/42545):

```js
x=>x.replace(/[A-Z]/gi,C=>   // Replace each letter C with
 String.fromCharCode(        //  the character with char code
  C.charCodeAt()+4^31))      //   the char code of C, plus 4, with the last 5 bits flipped.
```

Curse your incredibly long property names, JS...

Comment: +1 for mentioning JS's excruciatingly long property names. My favorite is still the infamous `document.getElementById`

Comment: @Cyoce Try `document.getElementsByClassName` or, on Firefox and Chrome, `document.DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC`

Comment: This seems to only be 66 bytes not 67

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ You're right about that, thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are missing a closing bracket on the end of the golfed code.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Thanks! I wondered why I had miscounted...

Comment: If the challenge didn't require case sensitivity, it could be [at least 14 bytes shorter](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/2dYuWk9PLzlWLzexQCPT1k7DxFS3ILGoONUzr0QjU8fYTLOmJlNTryQ/uKQoMy9dAyig@b8AyCzRSNNQ8kjNycnXUSjPL8pJUVTS1MvKz8zTUFICKgEA) :p

Answer (score 11):

### CJam, 17 bytes

I wanted to help GamrCorps golf his CJam solution, but the result ended up so different that I decided to make a separate answer.

```
q'[,_el^_W%32f^er
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q'%5B%2C_el%5E_W%2532f%5Eer&input=Hello%20World!)

#### Explanation

```
q     e# Read all input.
'[,   e# Get a character range from the null byte up to and including "Z".
_el   e# Duplicate and convert to lowercase.
^     e# Symmetric set difference. Due to the lowercase operation only letters will not
      e# appear in both sets, and so we get a string with all uppercase letters followed
      e# by all lowercase letters, i.e "ABC...XYZabc...xyz".
_W%   e# Duplicate and reverse. Gives: "zyx...cbaZYX...CBA".
32f^  e# Take each character XOR 32 which swaps the case, so now we have:
      e#                               "ZYX...CBAzyx...cba"
er    e# Transliterate: substitute each character in the first string with the correspoding
      e# character in the second string.
```

Comment: Well, I'm glad you were trying to help! That is the solution that I was trying to make, I just couldn't figure out the XOR. Nice Job!

Comment: SE's syntax highlighting hates esolangs.

Comment: @Cyoce They probably don't have time; given how many languages are on this site. That said, CJam is probably one of the easier ones, as it's not self-modifying and has a pretty clear structure. I'd like to see them try to add syntax-highlighting to a self-modifying language like ///.

Comment: @Challenger5 afaik, the syntax highlighting just uses Google's prettify, do support for various esolangs would have to be added there.

Answer (score 10):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>17</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Code:

```
\T`w`_dZ-Az-a
```

Explanation:

```
\             # This suppresses the trailing linefeed
 T            # Switches to transliterate mode
  `w          # w is short for _0-9A-Za-z
    `_d       # d is short for 0-9
       Z-Az-a # Z-Az-a
```

This does some magic stuff and completes the task.

Try it [here](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XFRgd2BfZFotQXotYQ&input=UHJvZ3JhbW1pbmcgUHV6emxlcyAmIENvZGUgR29sZg).

Comment: Lucky you that I recently added ``\``. Unlucky you that I didn't get around to adding character classes for letters and reversed character classes yet.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Very lucky indeed, that almost invalidated my answer :)

Comment: For reference, as of Retina 0.7.2 you could do `\T\`lL\`RlRL`.

Answer (score 9):

### Pyth, <s>10</s> 9

```
uXGr;H)2z
```

Thanks to Jakube for saving a byte with the new feature of `;`!

[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=uXGr%3BH%292z&input=Hello&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%0AProgramming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golf%0AHello%2C+World%21&debug=0)

A quick explanation: reduce starting with the input over the numbers 0 and 1. The operation to be performed is translate the lower case alphabet with either `r...0` or `r...1` which are the lower and upper functions from python, respectively, applied to it, and then reversed.

Comment: 9 bytes due to a new feature (not even a day old): `uXGr;H)2z`

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Comment: Can't you use `X` with the alphabet and then with the capitalized alphabet?

Comment: @xnor `XXzG)rG1`? That seems to work.

Comment: Or, maybe do X on the lowercase and uppercase alphabets concatenated, then swap case? That's probably longer, actually.

Comment: I'll post as CW.

Comment: @xnor your second idea seems to give me 10: `rXzsrBG1)2`

Answer (score 7):

## Julia, <s>74</s> <s>61</s> 47 bytes

```
s->replace(s,r"[a-z]"i,t->Char(31$Int(t[1])-4))
```

This is a lambda function that accepts a string and returns a string. To call it, assign it to a variable.

We match each letter using a regular expression and replace each letter with the ASCII character corresponding to 31 XOR the ASCII code for the letter, minus 4.

Comment: Wow, this is very elegant. I get a deprecation warning for `$` so you might want to update that to `⊻`. Didn't know that you can use a function in `replace`.

Answer (score 5):

## Japt, <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
Ur"[A-Za-z]"_c +4^31 d
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VXIiW0EtWmEtel0iX2MgKzReMzEgZA==&input=IlByb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMgJiBDb2RlIEdvbGYi)

#### How it works

```
Ur"[A-Za-z]"_  // Take the input and replace each letter with:
 c +4          //  Take its char code and add 4. This results in
               //  the string      "ABC...XYZabc...xyz"
               //  becoming        "EFG...\]^efg...|}~".
 ^31           //  XOR the result by 31. This flips its last five 5 bits.
               //  We now have     "ZYX...CBAzyx...cba".
 d             //  Convert back from a char code.
               // Implicit: output last expression
```

Comment: Nice idea (which I borrowed...) to use XOR for this

Answer (score 5):

### C, <s>150</s> 129 Bytes

```
void rev(char*s){int i,t;for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){t=s[i]+25;t=t<116?180-t:244-t;isalpha(s[i])?printf("%c",t):printf("%c",s[i]);}}
```

This function just converts char to int and adds the appropriate offset to the int before printing. I know it's not the shortest but I didn't see a C implementation.

Example usage

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void rev(char*s){int i,temp;for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){temp=s[i]+25;temp=temp<116?180-temp:244-temp;isalpha(s[i])?printf("%c",temp):printf("%c",s[i]);}}


int main(){
   char *s = "hello, there";
   rev(s);
   return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: shortened a variable name.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange! This is a very good approach. It could be golfed more by making all variables (including `temp`) exactly one character long.

Comment: Ahh you are right! I will regolf this one

Comment: If you need any help using some comment features like replying (`@username`), chat, notifications or anything else, feel free to just ask. (Anyone.)

Comment: Okay will do! Thanks @wizzwizz4

Comment: Do you think you could have a go at my challenge? [Analyse your Chair](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67522/analyse-your-chair)

Comment: @edc65 No need. The code would work without that (Assuming no extra compiler flags)

Comment: Yes it will work without the headers you just get a compiler warning @edc65 I figured since it compiles and runs it wouldn't be considered cheating but in real world use you should always include the headers.

Comment: I will be sure to give your challenge a go sometime tonight. I have an idea for it. @wizzwizz4

Comment: 107 bytes: `i,t;r(char*s){for(;i<strlen(s);i++){t=s[i]+25;t=t<116?180-t:244-t;isalpha(s[i])?putchar(t):putchar(s[i]);}}`

Comment: Oh yeah putchar that is a good call! Thanks @CoolGuy

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>69</s> 61 bytes

Thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312) for shaving off some extra bytes:

```
function(s)cat(chartr("a-zA-Z",intToUtf8(c(122:97,90:65)),s))
```

**Previous version:**

```
function(s)cat(chartr("a-zA-Z",rawToChar(as.raw(c(122:97,90:65))),s))
```

This is an anonymous function. Usage:

```
> f=function(s)cat(chartr("a-zA-Z",rawToChar(as.raw(c(122:97,90:65))),s))
> f("Hello, World!")
Svool, Dliow!
> f("Programming Puzzles & Code Golf")
Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou
> f("This is
+ a multiline
+ example.")
Gsrh rh
z nfogrormv
vcznkov.
```

Comment: `intToUtf8(c(122:97,90:65))` instead of the `raw` conversions, and you can get rid of the `cat` as well. I'm making it a bit of a habit to come golf 1+ year old answers of yours...

Answer (score 5):

## C, 64

A void function that modify the string in place.

```c
t(char*p){for(int c;c=*p;)*p++=c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?(c^31)-4:c;}
```

Test: [ideone](http://ideone.com/l1omcP)

Comment: `c;t(char*p){for(;c=*p;)*p++=c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?(c^31)-4:c;}`

Comment: @CoolGuy right, but I don't like the global inside a function... it's just me

Comment: Isn't this 64 bytes?

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ yes it is .. thanks ..

Answer (score 5):

### Python, 61 bytes

```python
lambda x:''.join([c,chr(ord(c)+4^31)][c.isalpha()]for c in x)
```

An anonymous function. On letters, does the reversing operation on the bit representation by adding 4, then flipping the last five bits, similar to [ETHproductions' Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68509/20260).

Comment: Just wrote the exact same thing haha

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 40 bytes

New solution: Stole that bit flipping magic from some of the other posts here:

```
->s{s.gsub(/[a-z]/i){($&.ord+4^31).chr}}
```

---

## Ruby, <s>55</s> 46 bytes

```rb
->s{s.tr'a-zA-Z',[*?A..?Z,*?a..?z].reverse*''}
```

9 bytes off thanks to @manatwork

---

test run:

```rb
->s{s.gsub(/[a-z]/i){($&.ord+4^31).chr}}["Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou"]
=> "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"
```

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 21 bytes

```
q'[,65>__el_@+W%@@+er
```

Not an optimal solution... yet... [Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%27%5B%2C65%3E__el_%40%2BW%25%40%40%2Ber&input=Hello%2C%20World!)

Its hard to explain without grouping things, so here is a general explanation: gets input, pushes uppercase alphabet twice and lowercase twice, rotates things around, combines uppercase and lowercase strings, reverses one, and uses transliteration (similar to the Retina answer).

Comment: Does this output a trailing newline?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 It shouldn't unless aditsu changed how the stack is outputted.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf, 15 bytes

```
~Ai+plpu+_pl_pu
~A              I don't know what to call this, besides "dictionary replace"
  i              the input
   +plpu         previous dictionary: lower + upper alphabet
        +_p1_pu  new dictionary: reversed lower + reversed upper
```

[Test suite](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=fkFpK3BscHUrX3BsX3B1&input=YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXoKCnp5eHd2dXRzcnFwb25tbGtqaWhnZmVkY2JhCgpQcm9ncmFtbWluZyBQdXp6bGVzICYgQ29kZSBHb2xmCgpLaWx0aXpubnJtdCBLZmFhb3ZoICYgWGx3diBUbG91CgpIZWxsbywgV29ybGQhCgpTdm9vbCwgRGxpb3ch), or [try it with your own input](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=fkFpK3BscHUrX3BsX3B1)

Comment: The word for this is "transliteration," FYI.

Answer (score 3):

### Seriously, 31 bytes

```
úúû+╗úRúûR+╝,`;╜íuWD╛E(X0WX`Mεj
```

Hex Dump:

```
a3a3962bbba352a396522bbc2c603bbda1755744be452858305758604dee6a
```

[Try It Online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=a3a3962bbba352a396522bbc2c603bbda1755744be452858305758604dee6a&input=Programming%20Puzzles)

Expl:

```
úúû+╗                             Put UPPERCASElowercase in reg0
     úRúûR+╝                      Put ESACREPPUesacrewol in reg1
            ,                     Fetch input.
             `             `Mεj   Map over the characters in string as list, joining result
              ;╜íu                Find 1-index of character in UPPERCASElowercase
                  W     0WX       If it is positive (present): 
                   D              Convert back to 0-index
                    ╛E            Look it up in ESACREPPUesacrewol
                      (X          Delete the original character.
                                  (Else just leave the original character unchanged.)
```

I just realized the spec say no additional whitespace, but there is no way to suppress trailing newlines in Seriously output, so there is no Seriously solution.

Comment: What does `ESACREPPUesacrewol` mean?

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ UPPERCASE reversed LOWERCASE reversed

Comment: the reversed uppercase alphabet prepended to the reversed lowercase alphabet

Answer (score 3):

## 2, 12 chars / 26 bytes (non-competitive)

```
ïĪ(ᶐ+ᶛ,ᶐᴙ+ᶛᴙ
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=Programming%20Puzzles%20%26%20Code%20Golf&code=%C3%AF%C4%AA%28%E1%B6%90%2B%E1%B6%9B%2C%E1%B6%90%E1%B4%99%2B%E1%B6%9B%E1%B4%99)</kbd>

Added transliterate function after the challenge was posted.

## Explanation

```
ïĪ(ᶐ+ᶛ,ᶐᴙ+ᶛᴙ // implicit: ï=input
ïĪ(           // transliterate ï...
   ᶐ+ᶛ,       // from uppercase+lowercase alphabet...
       ᶐᴙ+ᶛᴙ  // ... to reversed uppercase+reversed lowercase alphabet
              // implicit output
```

Comment: I thought  2 was going to be called  ∞?

Comment: No, I decided to save that for a complementary (but different) language for .

Comment: IIRC There is a blackboard bold 2.

Comment: @ՊՓԼՃՐՊՃՈԲՍԼ Call it ESMax (in doublestruck).

Answer (score 3):

## C (function), 50

```
f(char*s){for(;*s;s++)*s=isalpha(*s)?*s+4^31:*s;}
```

This builds on [all](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68587/11259) [three](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68550/11259) [previous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68560/11259) C answers, so credit to @Ruud, @Danwakeem and @edc65.

This function modifies a char array in place.

My understanding is [function entries are allowed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/11259) unless explicitly banned in the question.

[Try it online.](https://ideone.com/L5v8YF)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
žnžo‡
```

Uses **CP-1252** character set.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xb5uxb5v4oCh&input=YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXo)

Explanation:

```
žn    - Push [A-Za-z]
  žo  - Push [Z-Az-a]
    ‡ - Transliterate.
```

Comment: Why is this noncompeting?

Answer (score 3):

## PostgreSQL, <strike>118</strike> 125 bytes

```
SELECT s,TRANSLATE(s,t||UPPER(t),REVERSE(t)||REVERSE(UPPER(t)))
FROM(SELECT text'Programming Puzzles & Code Golf's,text'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz't)r
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8276/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╗
║                s                 ║            translate            ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ Programming Puzzles & Code Golf  ║ Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╝
```

Input: `SELECT text'...'s`

---

**EDIT:**

Input as table:

```
SELECT s,TRANSLATE(s,t||UPPER(t),REVERSE(t)||REVERSE(UPPER(t)))
FROM i,(SELECT text'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz't)r
GROUP BY s,t
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/15762/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╗
║                s                 ║            translate            ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ Hello, World!                    ║ Svool, Dliow!                   ║
║ Programming Puzzles & Code Golf  ║ Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou ║
║ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz       ║ zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba      ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Hey lad2025, I think this is shorter than 118, but I am no expert in the counting rules

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>195</s> <s>169</s> <s>168</s> 166 bytes

Thanks to [@TrangOul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30296/trang-oul) for -2 bytes!

How didn't I see that I could have golfed that down before?

```python
x=__import__('string').ascii_letters;y,z=x[26:],x[:26];a,b=y[::-1],z[::-1];print(''.join(b[z.index(i)]if i in b else a[y.index(i)]if i in a else i for i in input()))
```

(sorta) ungolfed:

```python
x = __import__('string').ascii_letters;
y, z = x[26: ], x[: 26];
a, b = y[::-1], z[::-1];
print(''.join(b[z.index(i)]
    if i in b
    else a[y.index(i)]
    if i in a
    else i
    for i in input()
))
```

[Try it on Ideone!](http://ideone.com/psNATq)

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by removing the outermost `[]` from `join`.

Comment: @TrangOul really? It's a list comprehension so I thought it needs to be a list or else you get `generator object <genexpr> at...`, but I will test it

Comment: @TrangOul Nevermind, I learned something, thanks!

Comment: Any iterable [containing `str` values] can be passed to `join()` function.

Answer (score 2):

### Unix shell + tr + printf, 35 bytes

```
tr A-Za-z `printf %s {Z..A} {z..a}`
```

Here you are, a canonical answer in tr. I thought how could a question to transliterate the alphabet go without a canonical answer to **tr**ansliterate the alphabet?

tr by itself does not even do a "Hello, World!" and as such isn't a programming language, so <s>I marked the answer as noncompeting</s><sup>[1]</sup>.

[1]: Edit: Actually, *Unix shell* is the language and tr is the *standard library*. Thanks to Downgoat and Digital Trauma for helping me spot this out.

Comment: I think its fine to claim shell or bash as a language, and common utilities (`tr` is in coreutils) as the standard library.  See countless of my answers ;-)

Comment: But it doesn't work: `tr: range-endpoints of 'Z-A' are in reverse collating sequence order`.   I think you have to do something like `tr A-Za-z $(printf %s {Z..A} {z..a})` (and replace `$( )` with backticks)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma but not everyone has printf on their system.

Comment: I think you'd have quite a hard time finding a Unix system that doesn't have `printf` - after all, [its specified by Posix](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/printf/).  Also its a builtin in bash which is pretty ubiquitous these days.  Regardless, having something pre-installed on everyone's system is not a prerequisite for [tag:code-golf] -  not everyone has CJam on their system either ;-)

Comment: The space between `}` and `{` is required - otherwise the expansion becomes something like `Zz Zy Zx ... Za Yz ... Aa`

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>119</s> 104 bytes

Saved 15 bytes thanks to @nimi.

```
c=fromEnum;s=toEnum;f[]="";f(x:y)|64<c x&&c x<91=s(155-c x):f y|96<c x&&c x<123=s(219-c x):f y|0<1=x:f y
```

**Usage:**

```
f "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"

f "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"
"Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou"

f "Hello, World!"
"Svool, Dliow!"
```

**Explanation**

```
let c=fromEnum;s=toEnum;--wrap names for later use, fromEnum gets ascii code from char, toEnum gets char from ascii code
f[]=[];                 --feed empty list (of chars in this case), get empty list
f(x:y)                  --feed a list, separate the first element and...
|64<c x&&c x<91=        --if its an uppercase char (using ascii code range)...
s(c x*(-1)+155)         --  inverse its ascii code value, move it to the range of uppercase and get the new char
                        --  (like rotating half turn a ruler by the side and then sliding it to the space it previously occupied)
:f y                    --  feed the rest of the list and stick the new char in front of the result
|96<c x&&c x<123=       --if its a lowercase char (using ascii code range)...
s(c x*(-1)+219)         --  inverse its ascii code value, move it to the range of lowercase and get the new char
:f y                    --  feed the rest of the list and stick the new char in front of the result
|True=x:f y             --otherwise feed the rest of the list and stick the char in front of the result
```

I'm new to Haskell... to functional programming... and to the site, and i know there are (a lot of) better answers to this question, but bear with me.

Comment: Some golfing tips: a) no need to use `let`. Start directly with `c=fromEnum`. Use `(155-c x)` and `(219-c x)`. c) `True`can be replaced by `1<2`. -- The code fails to load for me with the "ambigious type variable" error for functions `c` and `s` (ghci 7.10.2), but this can easily be fixed with `f[]=""` instead of `f[]=[]`.

Comment: Thanks!, i was actually wondering if it was valid without "let", since it doesnt run directly on GHC.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 28 bytes

```perl6
{S:g/\w/{chr $/.ord+4+^31}/}
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
# give it a lexical name
my &swap = { … }

say swap 'Programming Puzzles & Code Golf';
# Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou

say swap ('a'..'z').join
# zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
```

Comment: When I run this it says: `Warning: Use of "ord" without parentheses is ambiguous at (eval 8)[/System/Library/Perl/5.18/perl5db.pl:732] line 2.` I know nothing about perl so am I doing something wrong? How would I run this?

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ If you notice it says this is written in [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/) You can go to #perl6 on freenode and type `m: my &swap = {S:g/\w/{chr $/.ord+4+^31}/}; say swap ('a'..'z').join`

Comment: Ah okay, apparently I can't read :P

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ I added a note that you can test it on #perl6 on freenode

Answer (score 2):

### Java, 136 bytes

```
void x(String i){for(char c:i.toCharArray()){if(Character.isLetter(c))c=c<91?(char)(90-(c-65)):(char)(122-(c-97));System.out.print(c);}}
```

Example usage:

```
class Test {
  static void x(String i){for(char c:i.toCharArray()){if(Character.isLetter(c))c=c<91?(char)(90-(c-65)):(char)(122-(c-97));System.out.print(c);}}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    x("Programming Puzzles & Code Golf");
    // produces "Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou"
  }
}
```

Probably the worst commonly-used language in terms of byte size.

Comment: [Java's is a meme here actually](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5829/40695)

Comment: I know this has been posted about 1.5 year ago, but you can golf quite a few things like this: `void x(String i){for(Character c:i.toCharArray())System.out.print(c.isLetter(c)?(char)(c<91?90-(c-65):122-(c-97)):c);}` (**118 bytes**)

Comment: Or even shorter: `void y(String i){for(int c:i.getBytes())System.out.print((char)(c>65&c<91|c>96&c<123?c<91?90-(c-65):122-(c-97):c));}` (**116 bytes**)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You can also rearrange the calculations to negate the need for parentheses by making ```90-(c-65)``` into ```-c+65+90 ``` and ```122-(‌​c-97)``` into ```-c+97+122```, which saves a byte each.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, <s>164</s> 159 bytes

```
def f(t,a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",b=""):
 for c in t:u=64<ord(c)<91;c=c.lower();c=a[::-1][a.index(c)] if c in a else c;b+=c.upper() if u else c
 return b
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 73 bytes

```
<?=strtr($argv[1],($b=strtolower($a=join(range(A,Z)))).$a,strrev($a.$b));
```

do this need any comments?

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>28</s> 25 bytes

24 bytes of code + 1 for `-p`

```perl
s/\pL/chr(4+ord$&^31)/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP6bARz85o0jDRDu/KEVFLc7YUFM/PfX//4Ci/PSixNzczLx0hYDSqqqc1GIFNQXn/JRUBff8nDQuj9ScnHwdhfD8opwUxX/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 65 bytes

```powershell
-join($args|% t*y|%{[char]($_,(($_-bxor31)-4))[$_-match'[a-z]']})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBPS8NAEMXv@RTTsG2zkhxET4IgKCj0UlBQKKVsk02y7SST7m7@NG0/e1xrq3MYmB/vPZhXUSu1ySXiwFJ4hMMQbUiVARM6M8cx2Jv9cXxYxLnQy4CtwsCtaN2Rvrvl0T3nC3cWwsb5dCGifjldnvhw8rynwAM3YeCLdZzINMvVZotFSdVOG1s3bbfv/fBH4vf7rm1qa/SuorLA7UblWSqTeC18fg2Za8q0KApVZjCv@x6lgQk8UyLhlTC9JM0UWtWXpS4szFIhqMmd6gvbBj6Q6v@4N/cuhfBJGpPRxfzeEGEIL6ioHTkphyOM4XC2MBMCk10lYysTVxJb/WItTY3WgYnrjpkz9Flw4VEsd38u/nCV@95p@AY)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 22 bytes

```
σ…'A'Z…'Z'Aσ…'a'z…'z'a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//3zzo4Zl6o7qUSAqSt0Rwk9UrwJRVeqJ////T0xKTklNS8/IzMrOyc3LLygsKi4pLSuvqKwCAA)

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>112</s> 98 bytes

```c
i;main(){char x[99];gets(x);for(;x[i];i++)if(isalpha(x[i]))x[i]=(x[i]>90?219:155)-x[i];puts(x);}
```

I know that `gets()` is deprecated and unsafe, but `scanf()` doesn't accept whitespace and I need to include `stdio.h` if I want to `fgets` (since `stdin` is defined in `stdio.h`). I assume this program wouldn't work if the user tried to enter a string more than `99` characters.

EDIT: Changing `printf("%s",x)` to `puts(x)` saves `7` bytes and changing `i<strlen(x)` to `x[i]` saves another `7` bytes.

Comment: I find it interesting that I can't replace `i;main(){char x[99];` with `i,x[99];main{` (This changes the type to an `int`, which seems to cause the program to output garbled text). Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
kBklĿ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kBkl%C4%BF&inputs=Programming%20Puzzles%20%26%20Code%20Golf&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
kB     # Constant 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  kl   # Constant 'ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
    Ŀ  # Transliterate a(b -> c)
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 21 <s>28</s> bytes

Uses [version 6.0.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/6.0.0), which is earlier than this challenge. The code runs in Octave.

```
jttk2Y2mXK)o31Z~4-cK(
```

#### Example

```
>> matl
 > jttk2Y2mXK)o31Z~4-cK(
 >
> Hello, World!
Svool, Dliow!
```

#### Explanation

```
j             % input string
t             % duplicate
tk            % duplicate and convert to lowercase
2Y2           % string 'abc...xyz'
m             % "ismember" function: produces logical index of letter positions
XK            % copy to clipboard K
)             % index into string to get its letters
o31Z~4-       % bitwise XOR with 31 and subtract 4
c             % convert to char
K             % paste logical index from clipboard K
(             % put back modified letters into original string
```

#### Old approach, 28 bytes

```
j1Y2!tkh"t@2#m@0v27b-)wXK)K(
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 66 bytes

```
_|hH(:64>:91<,77-H+78=X;H:96>:123<,109-H+110=X;HX),[X]:"~c"w,?b:0&
```

The lack of built-ins really hurts here, so we have to resort to good old ASCII codes computations.

The predicate `brachylog_main` expects a character codes string as input and no output, e.g. `` brachylog_main(`Hello, World!`,_). ``

#### Explanation

```
_                                                                  § If the input is empty,
                                                                   § return true
                                                                   §
 |                                                                 § Else
                                                                   §
  hH(                                            ),[X]:"~c"w       § Print variable X which
                                                                   § depends on the head of
                                                                   § the input as a char code
                                                                   §
                                                            ,?b:0& § Recursive call on the
                                                                   § tail of the input
                                                                   §
     :64>:91<,77-H+78=X                                            § If H is capital, X =
                                                                   § 77 - H + 78
                       ;                                           § Else if H is non-cap, X=
                        H:96>:123<,109-H+110=X                     § 109 - H + 110
                                              ;                    § Else (not a letter)
                                               HX                  § H = X
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 61 bytes

```
@(x)[abs(-x+ismember(x,65:90)*155+ismember(x,97:122)*219),'']
```

I tried `f=@ismember`, and making the range `a=65:90` a variable and do `32+a` in the second `ismember`-call. All this shortened the code, but would result in a program and thus require both `disp` and `input`.

This gives:

```
ans('Hello, World!')
ans =
Svool, Dliow!

ans('Programming Puzzles & Code Golf')
ans =
Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 104 bytes

Pretty simple using [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans).

```python
from string import*
u=ascii_uppercase
l=u.lower()
f=lambda x:x.translate(maketrans(u+l,u[::-1]+l[::-1]))
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/0ORDA8)

This last line would also work, since `string` is imported:

```python
f=lambda x:translate(x,maketrans(u+l,u[::-1]+l[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, <s>40</s> 39 bytes

Since everyone else is doing anonymous functions:

```perl6
my &f=*.trans(/\w/=>{chr $/.ord+4+^31})
```

(Thanks @b2gills for the tip)

Uses the same bit flipping voodoo as some of the other posts.
I wasn't sure whether to include the variable/function declaration in the byte count, so I did just in case. Without it this solution is only 34 bytes.

Usage:

```
> f "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
> f "Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou"
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
> f "Svool, Dliow!"
Hello, World!
```

Comment: You can use `*.trans(…)` to make it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 105 bytes

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(:1,a||UPPER(a),REVERSE(UPPER(a)||a))FROM(SELECT'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'a FROM DUAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 92 bytes

```
[ [ 65 90 [a,b] dup >lower 2dup [ reverse ] bi@ append -rot append zip >hashtable at ] map ]
```

An anonymous function. Making it case insensitive is... expensive.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 69 bytes

```
while(""<$c=$argv[1][$i++])echo ctype_alpha($c)?chr(ord($c)+4^31):$c;
```

mapping stolen from [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68512#68512)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
žižk‡
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=ScW-acW-a-KAoQ&input=QWJDZEVmR2hJaktsTW5PcFFyU3RVdld4WXo)

```
       # Push input.
 ži    # Push [a-zA-Z]
   žk  # Push [z-aZ-A]
     ‡ # Transliterate a#(b -> c)
```

Comment: Implicit input... you can remove the `I`.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 332 bytes

```
(let p((l(map char->integer(string->list s)))(ol'())(g(λ(n a b)(and(> n a)(< n b))))(t first)(c cons))
(cond[(empty? l)(list->string(map integer->char(reverse ol)))][(and(not(g(t l)96 123))(not(g(t l)64 91)))(p(rest l)(c(t l)ol)g t c)]
[(>(t l)95)(p(rest l)(c(- 122(-(t l)97))ol)g t c)][else(p(rest l)(c(- 90(-(t l)65))ol)g t c)]))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define(f s)
  (let p ((l (map char->integer (string->list s)))
             (ol '())
             (g (λ (n a b) (and (> n a) (< n b))))
             (t first)
             (c cons))
    (cond
      [(empty? l)
       (list->string (map integer->char (reverse ol)))]
      [(and(not (g (t l) 96 123)) (not(g(t l) 64 91)))
       (p (rest l) (c (t l) ol) g t c)]
      [(> (t l) 95)
       (p (rest l) (c (- 122 (- (t l) 97)) ol) g t c)]
      [else
       (p (rest l) (c (- 90 (- (t l) 65)) ol) g t c)]
      )))
```

Testing:

```
(f "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
(f "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf")
(f "Hello, World!")
```

Output:

```
"zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"
"Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou"
"Svool, Dliow!"
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 234 Bytes

Golfed:

```
string A(string s){string a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",z=string.Concat(a.Reverse()),o="";s.ToList().ForEach(c=>o+=!z.Contains(char.ToLower(c))?c:char.IsLower(c)?z[a.IndexOf(c)]:char.ToUpper(z[a.IndexOf(char.ToLower(c))]));return o;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public string A(string s)
{
  string a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    z = string.Concat(a.Reverse()), o = "";
  s.ToList().ForEach(c => o += !z.Contains(char.ToLower(c)) ? c :
  char.IsLower(c) ? z[a.IndexOf(c)] :
  char.ToUpper(z[a.IndexOf(char.ToLower(c))]));
  return o;
}
```

Testing:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Atbash().A("Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"));
Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou

Console.WriteLine(new Atbash().A("Hello, World!"));
Svool, Dliow!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ØAµ,Uµ;Œsðy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394huOhrTqhh7ZaH51UfHhD5f///6sqK8rLSkuKiwoL8vNyc7KzMjPS01JTkpMSubwzc0oyq/LyinJLFLzTEhPzyzIU1BQicsrLFEJy8ku5gsvy83N0FFxyMvPLFbk80nOyFbLTMopByvOSFCrT0tNzcjMUAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 110 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(map-into s(lambda(x)(if(alpha-char-p x)(code-char(-(if(upper-case-p x)155 219)(char-code x)))x))s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYy9DoIwFIV3n6IymDaxAyYMzg46sjlfSoHqbXttQZGXx5bE4QznOz8KTaSVUzBOMb5yBNu0wKPgFkgaN3oW/3AW3HQckAaQaoAgiSWkfKs3y2WOJyIdpIKot7isKnYqz6mWB7mboBBJUYi1gEa1uusH83iidZ5eIY7T@zN/l10dfB/AWuN6Vk/LgjqyA7vkh6vHbnfTiP7I7j5guy/S2Q8)

Very straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 114 bytes

```
(a=Alphabet[];b=Capitalize/@a;r:=Reverse;u=AssociationThread[a~Join~b->r@a~Join~r@b];StringJoin[Characters@#/.u])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY3BTsMwEETv@QpTpAokoPdGRq7KiV4Q7QEpymGdOvWC4w2bjQM59NdDkJDgC7jNaN7MNCDeNSBYwTRdgd6E1oN1UpS51VtoUSDg6FYGcl7rZ5ccdy7v9abrqMK5R/Hg2cGxgPMjYTzb23s2P5qNLfO9MMbTty@2HhgqmSfM5equL6@XU73W//@aPc2hFLVZjJ8fQ@ql4/eWYhPeXtGfanesLCzKX2qHQXCMkRtRuxqAkldL9RKGpA6B@r/oPhGFG/UQkIaLOciy6Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 32 bytes

```
{x^'![t,_t;(|t),|_t:`c$65+!26]x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqroiTl0xukQnvsRao6ZEU6cmvsQqIVnFzFRb0cgstqL2f5qCUmJSckpqWnpGZlZ2Tm5efkFhUXFJaVl5RWWVEhdQOqAoP70oMTc3My9dIaC0qiontVhBTcE5PyVVwT0/Jw2sxiM1JydfRyE8vygnRVHpPwA)

Builds a dictionary mapping the letters to their "reverses", filling any non-letter character with what was in the input.

- `` t:`c$65+!26 `` build a list of the letters from `"A"` through `"Z"`, storing in `t`
- `![t,_t;(|t),|_t:...]` build a dictionary mapping the letters to their reverses
- `x^'![...]x` index into that dictionary with the input. non-letter characters in the input get replaced with `" "`'s, so replace those spaces with whatever was in the input

## [k4](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/), 24 bytes

```
{x^![|,/|l;,/l:.Q`a`A]x}
```

Similar to the above, but benefits from using the built-in lists of characters; `.Q.A` for uppercase letters, and `.Q.a` for the lower case ones.

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 33 bytes

```
q['a{_)}25*]_eu+['z{_(}25*]_eu+er
```

Explanation:

```
q                   e# Read all input an put string to the stack
[                   e# Start array (char)
    'a              e# Put 'a' char to the stack
    {               e# Begin of code block
        _           e# Duplicate top element on the stack
        )           e# Increment the duplicate
    }               e# End of code block
    25*             e# Repeat code block 25 times
]                   e# End array
_                   e# Duplicate array
eu                  e# Uppercase the duplicate
+                   e# And join arrays
['z{_(}25*]_eu+     e# Repeat the same thing back from Z
er                  e# Replace A-z with z-A in the input
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 141 bytes

Similar to [@cat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68516/47947), but uses a `dict` to map letters and uses a simpler comprehension for the print:

```
a=__import__('string').ascii_letters;l,u=a[:26],a[26:];m=dict(zip(a,l[::-1]+u[::-1]));print(''.join(m[c] if c in a else c for c in input()))
```

Ungolfed:

```
a = __import__('string').ascii_letters; # import alphabet
l, u = a[:26],a[26:];                   # separate lower/uppercase
m = dict(zip(a, l[::-1] + u[::-1]));    # create map a-z+A-Z -> z-a+Z-A
print(''.join(m[c] if c in a else c     # if input char in map, map it
                   for c in input()))   # otherwise leave it alone
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, 96 bytes

```
var R=i=>i.replace(/[A-z]/g,s=>String.fromCharCode(155-s.charCodeAt(0)+(/[a-z]/.test(s)?64:0)))
```

Not as good as the other JavaScript answer, but I thought I'd try myself.

Comment: Your `A-z` regex matches `[\]^_\``, none of which should be modified. You'll probably want `A-Za-z`.

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 88 bytes

```
b=xrange(a,z)
a=lower(b)
do forever
  parse pull n
  say translate(n,reverse(b||a),a||b)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 57 bytes

```
s=>{var k;for(var a=s.length-1;a>0;a--){k+=s[a]}return k}
```

Comment: Does it work? How? `s[s.length] === undefined`

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica 89 Bytes

```
StringReplace[#,Thread[#~Join~#3@#->#2@#~Join~#2@#3@#]&[Alphabet[],Reverse,ToUpperCase]]&
```

48 Bytes of this is just long function names

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 116 bytes

```
t={}for i=65,90 do a=('').char(i)b=a.char(155-i)t[a],t[a:lower()]=b,b:lower()end print((io.read"*all"):gsub("%a",t))`
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python3

This is my first post on Code Golf; but I think I understood your question successfully;

This python3 code replaces abc -> xyz (as you specified above)

```
def ASUB(m,A,B):o = m.maketrans(A,B);r = m.translate(o);return(r);
ASUB(m="Programming Puzzles & Code Golf",
     A="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
     B="zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA")
#'Svool, Dliow!'
#'Kiltiznnrmt Kfaaovh & Xlwv Tlou'
```

the output of the both messages (Hello, World! and the other one) is in # comments

**EDIT: Thanks for clarifying caird coinheringaahing!**

Improved:

```
def A(m):o=m.maketrans("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA");return m.translate(o);
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a nice first answer, but there are a couple of issues. First, we require answers to code golf challenges to attempt to golf as much as possible, which, for Python, includes 1 letter variable names, and removing unnecessary whitespace. Secondly, as this calls for 1 input (`m`), your function shouldn't take `A` and `B` as parameters, rather you should include the full strings in your answer. [Here](https://tinyurl.com/y587fnkq) is a version of your answer that's slightly more golfed (156 bytes), and follows the site rules on functions

Comment: Oh, thanks so much for the  kind and clear, as swell as detailed explanation! and the other version! I can't  thank you enough! Should I edit or remove my post because of these issues?  Thanks again!

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer, just needs a little bit of improvement, which is exactly what SE's edit feature is for!

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ØẠŒsU,Ɗy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjIe7FhydVByqc6yr8r/O4fasRw1zFHTtFB41zNWM/P9fKTEpOSU1LT0jMys7Jzcvv6CwqLiktKy8orJKSUdBKaAoP70oMTc3My9dIaC0qiontVhBTcE5PyVVwT0/Jw2kxANoUb6OQnh@UU6KohIA)

### How it works

```
ØẠŒsU,Ɗy - Main link. Takes S on the left
ØẠ       - Yield "ABC...XYZabc...xyz"
      Ɗ  - Last three links as a monad f("ABC...XYZabc...xyz"):
  Œs     -   Swapcase
    U    -   Reverse
     ,   -   Pair
       y - Translate S by this mapping
```