# Using two linked programs, output ordinal numbers up to n

Tags: code-golf

> ...Ordinal numbers (or ordinal numerals) are words representing position or rank in a sequential order.

[image]

*From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics)).*

Your task is, using 2 separate programs (of which can be made from 2 different languages), to output the ordinal sequence from first to `nth`. You will be outputting the full word `second` as opposed to `2nd`.

The challenge of ordinal numbers has been brought up before, particularly in [this entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4707/outputting-ordinal-numbers-1st-2nd-3rd). In this challenge, ordinals are merely a vehicle to facilitate the unique conditions detailed below.

---

### Part 1

You must make a program that, when given the input of `n` must output *anything*.
`n` will always be a positive, non-zero integer no larger than 999.

Valid output includes but **is not limited to**:

- Any output to `stdout` / `stderr` / etc
- Creation of files / folders / etc
- A graphical interface or images of any kind

***Anything goes.***

---

### Part 2

You must make a program that uses the output of part 1's program to output a sequence of ordinal numbers, starting from 1 (first), up to whatever `n` was parsed in part 1.

#### General Conditions:

- The total bytes for part 2 must not exceed the total bytes for part 1 (less than or equal to).

#### Output conditions:

- Not case sensitive.
- Output must contain only the ordinal sequence (only characters a-Z) and whitespace (newlines allowed).
- Can be output to any source, so long as it is visible either during or after execution.
- Program does not need to terminate so long as its output is correct.
- Output is not required to have any grammar, but may optionally include it (hyphens, commas, "ands", etc). `nine hundred ninety ninth` is just as acceptable as `nine hundred and ninety-ninth`.

#### Sample Output

*Where `n` is 8*

```
FIRST SECOND THIRD FOURTH FIFTH SIXTH SEVENTH EIGHTH
```

---

### Scoring

The hierarchy of win conditions is:

> 1. The lowest number of bytes in part 1
> 2. The lowest number of bytes in part 2

```
Entry #1 | Part 1 = 32 bytes, Part 2 = 22 bytes
Entry #2 | Part 1 = 31 bytes, part 2 = 30 bytes

Entry #2 wins - Part 1 contains 31 bytes vs 32 bytes

---

Entry #1 | Part 1 = 21 bytes, Part 2 = 33 bytes
Entry #2 | Part 1 = 80 bytes, Part 2 = 70 bytes

Entry #2 wins - Entry #1 disqualified (Part 2 contains more bytes than Part 1)

---

Entry #1 | Part 1 = 50 bytes, Part 2 = 49 bytes
Entry #2 | Part 1 = 50 bytes, Part 2 = 50 bytes

Entry #1 wins - Part 1 is equal, Part 2 contains 49 bytes vs 50 bytes
```

Comment: What's the point in part 1 (as in, why couldn't this challenge just be scored on shortest submission for part 2)? Also, in your second scoring example, isn't the first entry invalid (part 2 > part 1), and if not, wouldn't it beat the second entry? Also, I recommend having at least a link to a formal ruleset for defining ordinals; for example, is 111 supposed to say `one hundred and eleventh` or `one hundred eleventh`?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I think the idea is to try to split the work between the two as evenly as possible while golfing -- if I make p1 output `[30, 'second']` for `32` then p2 has less work to do that if it had output, just `32`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something stupid, but of the last two entries in the scoring examples, why doesn't entry 1 win? part 1 has same bytes, part 2 is less than or equal to part 1 for both, and entry 1 part 2 has less bytes than entry 2 part 2.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Because Part 2 must contain **equal or fewer** bytes to Part 1.  Since Part 1 is 21 bytes, but Part 2 is 33 bytes, Entry #1 is disqualified.  Unfortunately, that information is tucked away and not explicitly stated in the win conditions at the moment.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts This is important, because otherwise you could use a language that implicitly passes input as output when a 0 byte program is run for Part 1

Comment: @Chronocidal I said last two entries. 50 49 and 50 50. Not 21 33 and 80 70. I understand why the second two entries are scored that way. It appears the question was edited after I pointed that out.

Answer (score 14):

## [Sledgehammer 0.5.1](https://github.com/tkwa/Sledgehammer/commit/9e4f8257aae28f8aa0660948d2141e2745c15100) / Sledgehammer 0.5.1, 10 bytes

#### Program 1 (10 bytes):

```
⣘⢷⠾⣃⢖⣎⢅⡨⠱⢳
```

Decompresses into this Wolfram Language function:

```
{Range[#1], "Ordinal"} &
```

#### Program 2 (7 bytes):

```
⡾⡁⢚⣷⣬⠤⣾
```

Decompresses into this Wolfram Language function:

```
StringRiffle[IntegerName @@ #1, " "] &
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYy7DoMgFIZ3n@IPJk4uuDE0Ye1SjY6E4cQeKIkwkLOZPjsyf5dM8uNMkk5qLWi8cO9UIrtR@1mt9ZsKXeo/tbB0dkhNJe4phIvduwhHrh/KDGsx6hkKymMahq1r4npi0Z8WxhjfHg)

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) (with `english` package), 16 bytes / 16 bytes

#### Part 1, 16 bytes

```r
f=function(n)1:n
```

#### Part 2, 16 bytes

```r
english::ordinal
```

Requires the `english` package (which is not installed on TIO, unfortunately).

`english::ordinal(f(22))` outputs `first second third fourth fifth sixth seventh eighth ninth tenth eleventh twelfth thirteenth fourteenth fifteenth sixteenth seventeenth eighteenth nineteenth twentieth twenty first twenty second`.

Of course, part 1 could be made much shorter (3 bytes: `seq`), but that would go against the constraint that part 2 has to be no longer than part 1.

Comment: @Giuseppe Sure. Although I would argue that CRAN packages are part of R, and so should be allowed as long as we count the characters needed to load and attach them.

Comment: I believe meta consensus is that using an external library essentially counts as "another language"; see for instance [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14337/67312) which is about compiler flags, but has a note about Python external libraries. [The answer here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17636/67312) is instructive with many examples but I can't seem to use the search function on meta to find the definitive statement.

Comment: @Giuseppe Continued in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51052875#51052875

Answer (score 8):

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/) (both parts), 18 bytes / 15 bytes

-5/-1 thanks to [lirtosiast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188363/output-ordinal-numbers-up-to-n/188367?noredirect=1#comment451280_188367)

#### Part 1, 18 bytes

```
Range@#|"Ordinal"&
```

#### Part 2, 15 bytes

```
IntegerName@@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PygxLz3VQblGyb8oJTMvMUdJ7X@6LZdnXklqemqRX2JuqoODshpXQFFmXkl0ukOag0UsEsfQyDj2PwA)

Two functions which output via return value.

Comment: `Range@#|"Ordinal"&` is shorter, and `IntegerName` vectorizes over the first argument. I think space-separated output might be required, though.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3(part 1 & part 2)

Unfortunately Nodebox is very wordy... there is not much room for golfing.

#### Part 1 76 bytes

```
for  i  in  range  (  1 ,  int  (  input  (  ) ) + 1 ) : print ( i ,end=" ")
```

#### Part 2 (Uses the [NodeBox](https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics) library) 76 bytes

```
import en.number as n
for i in input().split():print(n.ordinal(n.spoken(i)))
```

Comment: Your answer must be valid; in this case, your part 2 is longer than your part 1, which is invalid. You cannot mark an answer as "non-competing" and submit an invalid submission; the "non-competing" label is a deprecated label for challenges submitted in languages or language versions that postdate the challenge, which used to be typically disallowed, but allowed under "non-competing" status for interesting submissions anyway.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Sorry, I thought the rules required Part 1 to be shorter than Part 2. I marked this as non-competing because it used a library to solve this problem.

Comment: Technically, using external libraries seems to be alright: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188

Comment: `import en.number as n` saves you four bytes in each part.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (Node.js), 47 bytes / 47 bytes

Two functions in the same Node.js environment, invoked like `g(f(n))`. Uses the npm package [number-to-words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-words).

#### Part 1, 47 bytes (40 bytes + 7 spaces)

```
n=>H=>{for(i=0;i<n;)console.log(H(++i))}
```

#### Part 2, 47 bytes

```
F=>F(require("number-to-words").toWordsOrdinal)
```

[Try it on Runkit!](https://runkit.com/5d2e1bc6298e33001a1b8926/5d2e1bc68e898b001a939f05)

---

## JavaScript (Node.js), 48 bytes / 43 bytes

#### Part 1, 48 bytes

```
n=>[n,require("number-to-words").toWordsOrdinal]
```

#### Part 2, 43 bytes

```
([n,F])=>{for(i=0;i<n;)console.log(F(++i))}
```

[Try it on Runkit!](https://runkit.com/5d2e1bc6298e33001a1b8926/5d2e1ea4298e33001a1b8e13)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5.10 / Common Lisp, 34 / 26 bytes

So, Common Lisp `format` has this as a built-in, because of course it does.

### Program 1 (34 bytes)

```
say"(format t\"~:r \"$_)"for 1..<>
```

Perl does all the iterating. The equivalent Common Lisp code (`(dotimes(i(read)) ...)`) is longer than the much golfier Perl `... for 1..<>`. Perl outputs a bunch of Common Lisp code.

### Program 2 (26 bytes)

```
(loop(eval(read nil nil)))
```

It's a REPL, minus the P. It reads standard input and, well, executes it. Doesn't terminate, but the rules explicitly say that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 2/2 bytes

```
ɾ, # print range (1,n+1)
```

```
∆o # nth ordinal of each
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLJvixcbuKIhm8iLCIiLCI2Il0=)